# regsvr32 Custom ocx file not Registering

Tags: vba, windows-xp, regsvr32

I've been asked to install an old VB program on an XP computer, but when I do I get an error when I run the program saying that Component 'filename.ocx' or one of its dependencies is not correctly registered: a file is missing or invalid.

This is a custom file (I did not create it), I have tried regsvr32 and I get no error messages but no successfully registered messages either.

This program also runs on another computer which this ocx file is not registered but opens without error. So my question would be what could cause the file to not be recognized by regsvr32, and run on another client with the same os, but without error. Any ideas, or new paths to look into would be very helpful.

Also if you dislike something about this question, let me know what it is, so I can fix it in the future. Down voting a question gives me no insight on why this upsets the community, it just discourages me to want to help others in areas I do understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do get the error "Component 'filename.ocx' or one of its dependencies is not correctly registered: a file is missing or invalid" from a custom dll or ocx file, it may just need that file and its dependent files in the directory that your running the executable, as was the problem in my case.

After adding the file to the root directory, and not registering any files the program opened fine. Maybe this helps someone else.